# Transferring custom instructions in a shared chat

Tags: openai-api

I have created custom instructions in ChatGPT (free version). When I try to share my chat iwth a friend I want the custom instructions to apply to him when he continues the conversation.
However, while he can continue the conversation my custom instructions are not applied.
Is there a solution around this problem?

I tried to share the chat, and I expected the conversation to be moderated by my custom instructions